# Is $\textrm{im}(f)$ homeomorphic to the torus less the inner equator?

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, surfaces

Consider the map $id_{S^1}\times f:S^1\times [0, 1]\longrightarrow S^1\times S^1$ where $f:[0, 1]\longrightarrow S^1$ is given by $$f(t)=(\cos(\pi t), \sin(\pi t)).$$ Is it true that $\textrm{im}(f)$ is homeomorphic to the torus $S^1\times S^1$ less the inner equator:

[image]

In the above picture the blue part is the equator to be removed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not quite. Think about the fact that the equator is a closed subset of the torus. What does that say about its complement (open vs closed)? How does that compare to $\operatorname{im}(f)$?

Comment: Well, $\textrm{im}(f)$ is closed for it is the image of a compact set by a continuous function and $\textrm{im}(f)\subset S^1\times S^1$ and $S^1\times S^1$ is Hausdorff..

Comment: @PtF: Great. So how does that compare to the equator-less torus? Thinking about compactness is ideal.

Comment: Well $\textrm{im}(f)$ is compact and the torus less the equator is not compact, hence they can't be homeomorphic..

Comment: what subset of $S^1\times S^1$, $\textrm{im}(f)$ will be homeomorphic to?

Comment: @PtF: Try to piece it together. Your map has the form $\operatorname{id}_{S^1} \times f$, so the image should be of the form $S^1 \times A$ for some subset $A \subset T^2$.

Comment: Well $\textrm{im}(f)$ will be the part of the torus above the $xy$-axis in $\mathbb R^3$, but I was looking for another way of seeing it..

Comment: It depends what you mean. $\operatorname{im}(f)\subset S^1 \times S^1$ is naturally a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2 \times \mathbb{R}^2=\mathbb{R}^4$, not $\mathbb{R}^3$, so there isn't exactly a notion of "above the $xy$-axis". But you are correct that the image is homeomorphic to the (closed) upper half of the torus pictured in your original post.

Comment: I agree with you.. That was an abuse saying "above the $xy$-axis"..

Comment: So do you understand now? We have $\operatorname{im}(\operatorname{id}_{S^1} \times f)=S^1\times \operatorname{im}(f)$, where $\operatorname{im}(f)$ is a half-circle.

Comment: Yes.. Indeed I asked the wrong question, I'd like to know if $\textrm{im}(f)^c$ is homeomorphic to the torus less the inner equator and I have already concluded it holds..

Comment: $\operatorname{im}(f)^c$ is a subset of $S^1$, not the torus, so I believe you mean $\operatorname{im}(\operatorname{id}_{S^1} \times f)^c$. Anyway, one should make a habit of selecting an answer once a question is resolved.

Comment: That's right =D